# Prevent vertical scrolling beyond div

Tags: javascript, html, css, android-webview

I am working on an Android app that makes use of HTML in a `WebView`.

I have a series of `<div>`s in my HTML. Something like this:

> `<body>`
>
> > > `<div id='topdiv'></div>`
> > >
> > > `<div id='contentdiv'>`
> > >
> > > > > `<p>A bunch of content in here!<p>`
> > > > >
> > > > > `<p>There is more content here than can fit on 1 screen.<p>`
> > >
> > > `</div>`
> > >
> > > `<div id='bottomdiv'></div>`
>
> `</body>`

**Is there a way to make it so that `bottomdiv` or `topdiv` is rendered, but not scrollable?** In other words, is there a way to prevent the user from scrolling down past `contentdiv` even though `bottomdiv` exists below it and is not invisible, but `contentdiv` is always fully scrollable?

I am open to any plain JavaScript, CSS, or HTML implementation. It would be nice if that was a feature you could turn on and off, but not necessary.

Since I am working exclusively on a mobile device, it does not help me to disable the scrollbar or capture `mousescroll` events and the like.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your goal is, but does setting #bottomDiv to position: absolute achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: I am trying to create a scenario where the bottom of #contentdiv acts as if it is the bottom of the browser and cannot scroll down anymore. I do not believe position:absolute will help because I want to be able to set #bottomdiv to not be able to show on the visible screen. This begs the question of why have the #bottomdiv at all, but the reason I need it is probably beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: #bottomdiv{ position: absolute; bottom: -999px; }

Comment: ^ the same could be applied to any element, moving it top/left/right/bottom off the screen.  You may need overflow: hidden on a container element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well what you want, the following can solve your problem. Use the overflow property on the body tag, like this:

```
body
{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Another way to solve it would be to set your `bottomdiv` to `hidden`, either by using 
    `visibility:hidden;`
if you want it to take no space or using 
    `display:hidden;`
if you want it not to take any space.
Than, just change it with javascript according to what you want to do.

Comment: None of them have any effect when applied to `body`, `div`s or classes in CSS. My div always takes up space and is scrollable. I want it to take up space, I just do not want to be able to scroll to it to look at it.

Comment: Set a height to the body tag and then put the `overflow:hidden;`. That will work.

Comment: It has no effect. I don't know why a `WebView` would ignore it? At any rate, if it did work woudln't that eleminate all scrolling in the `<body>`? If my middle content is larger than one screen (which it is) then I am stuck and cannot scroll through it.

Comment: That is bizarre.. it works for me here. If you don't want to do that with the body, create a wrapper div around what you want not to have a scroll bar, set a height (`height:100%` or `height:100px;` or whatever you need) and set `overflow:hidden;`. I just tested it here and it works perfectly for me. Everything is rendered, the extra conten is not shown and i cant scroll down

Comment: While this was not working for me in my situation, I think this is the right answer for most cases, so I am accepting it anyway. Thanks!